# How do you iterate through the IndexCollection of each table in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Tags: sql-server, smo

I am trying to get lists of indexes and constraints per table in my `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` application and I am having a hard time get the list of indexes to begin with.

If I am not mistaken each table has an `Indexes` property which is of type `IndexCollection` and it looks like it has a collection of `IndexCollections` as its items or elements.

For example if I have a reference to a SQL Server table called `tbl` I can refer to the indexes collection as follows:

```
tbl.Indexes
```

How do you iterate through the `Indexes` collection and get the list of indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// iterate over the indexes for this table
foreach (Index ix in tbl.Indexes)
{
    string indexName = ix.Name;
    string indexType = ix.IndexType.ToString();
    string indexFilter = ix.FilterDefinition;
}
```

The `IndexCollection` is a collection of objects of type `Index`, which then contain a number of properties to get information about your indexes,.